# Create a smudge effect color in background css

Tags: css

I'm currently trying to recreate the following background design:

[image]

I have tried many variations from using [linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient) to [conic-gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/conic-gradient). I wasn't able to make this using CSS only.

Is it possible to create this background using CSS only? If yes, could someone point me to the right direction?

I would like to avoid using a background image here

Comment: Please post what you actually tried, and what specific issue(s) you had with it.  Someone might be able to help you fix it.

Comment: Please add some details, do you just want a vage circle in the middle? How about the colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS background as several radial-gradients:

```css
* { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

body {  
  font: 16px/1.4 sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.12em;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(circle at 20% 20%, hsla(100, 60%, 30%, 0.2) 0%, transparent 30%),
    radial-gradient(circle at 40% 30%, hsla(150, 60%, 30%, 0.2) 0%, transparent 30%),
    radial-gradient(circle at 60% 40%, hsla(250, 60%, 30%, 0.2) 0%, transparent 30%),
    radial-gradient(circle at 80% 50%, hsla(340, 60%, 30%, 0.2) 0%, transparent 30%);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer doesn't directly solve my issue but points me in the right direction. I wasn't aware you could actually have several `radial-gradient` in a `background-image`.

Comment: You're welcome. With the right colors HSL values and with more circles you can recreate the above design **1:1**. I don't have the time to create the full circle and nitpick the necessary colors. You can do it.

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for. Not the CSS ready but some direction where to go and solve the challenge myself. Thank you