# Create a smudge effect color in background that makes a circle css

Tags: html, css

This is part two of the Netflix series: [Bruno Francisco Tries CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73830332/create-a-smudge-effect-color-in-background-css)

I'm currently trying to recreate the following design:

[image: design example]

The idea is to create a circle in the center of the div with 3 to 4 different colors blurred.

My idea is to create a `repeating-conic-gradient` with 3 different colors, then overlap this `repeating-conic-gradient` with a `radial-gradient` that "cuts" the circle. Something like this:

[image]

What I have tried so far:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__background"></div>
  <h1>Foo bar</h1>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.container__background {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(white, transparent 30%, white),
    repeating-conic-gradient(
      from 0deg at 50% 50%,
      #c8c9dc 0deg,
      #c9c3dc 10deg,
      #d4d8dc 20deg
    );
  filter: blur(10px);

  background-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

You can check the [codepen here](https://codepen.io/bfrancisco11/pen/OJZzwzd?editors=1100). I'm not 100% sure that this approach to the problem is the best one because I'm being unable to make the "smudges" look like circles right next to each other that will form a wilder circle.

Anyone has any idea on how I could approach this problem?

The requirement here would be to have this gradient be able to fit in any div no matter the size. It would be centered to the `div` and expand to its max width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this answer your question?

See the snippet below.

*Lep pozdrav iz Slovenije. :)*

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, white 0%, white 30%, transparent 50%, transparent 60%, white 80%);
}

.container__background {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: repeating-conic-gradient( #c8c9dc 0deg 30deg, #c9c3dc 30deg 60deg, #d4d8dc 60deg 90deg);
  filter: blur(30px);
  background-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__background"></div>
  <h1>Something here</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Najlepša hvala :)